# Auth0-js and usePostMessage flag

Tags: typescript, types, auth0

I am having problems compiling an Angular app that uses [auth0-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-js) package. The `renewAuth(options: RenewAuthOptions, callback: Auth0Callback<any>): void;` method used in the code (but also [in the examples](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v8#using-renewauth-to-acquire-new-tokens)) uses a parameter `{usePostMessage: true}`, which is not compatible with the `RenewAuthOptions` interface found in `"@types/auth0-js": "^8.3.0"` which does not include that property.

How should I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add properties to the interface. You can add this to a separate custom `*.d.ts` file or in the same `*.ts` file where you need it:

```
declare module "auth0-js" {
    interface RenewAuthOptions {
        usePostMessage: boolean
    }
}
```

---

But if you think that this is a valid property supported by the library you can raise a PR against the [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/auth0-js) with the updated property so it is available for everyone.